# regular expression to validate webservice

Tags: jquery

I need a regular expression for validation of webService. I tried different, but didnt work.

e.g.

```
addNotificationForm_webURLAdd-regexp=^[(http|https)://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?]
```

but it gives me error:

```
Coercion of (http|https)://([w-]+.)+[w-]+(/[w- ./?%&=]*)? to type java.util.regex.Pattern (via String --> java.util.regex.Pattern) failed: Illegal character range near index 34 (http|https)://([w-]+.)+[w-]+(/[w- ./?%&=]*)? ^
```

Please help.

Comment: Is this jQuery or Java?

Comment: What are you trying to validate? the name of the Web Service methods?

Comment: Please give examples: matching and non-matching expected inputs.

Comment: It's old. But the webservice could be like "http(s)://ip(hostname)/context-path